# Specifying a Window Procedure for child Windows

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, wndproc, createwindowex

I would like to know if its possible to specify a WndProc for a Child Window created by `CreateWindowEx`.

I have created a Window Class, the Main Window, the Window Procedure and a Message Loop already. The code works and I decided to keep it out for the clarity of my question.

This is my Window Proc, so far:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
        // Creation of the Win32 Window
        case WM_CREATE:
            // Add an Edit Field
            CreateWindowEx(
                WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
                "EDIT",
                "",
                WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
                5, 5, 200, 24,
                hwnd,
                (HMENU)100,
                g_Instance, // Comming from WinMain
                NULL
            );
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, lParam, wParam);
        case WM_KEYDOWN:
            // Track key presses on the edit field
            std::cout << "The key with the code " << wParam << " was pressed." << std::endl;
            return 0;
        case WM_PAINT:
            // Some painting code...
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, lParam, wParam);
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, lParam, wParam);
    }
}
```

I expected key presses on the child Edit Field that I created to throw a WM_KEYDOWN message, but they dont! The keys just get added to the Edit Field in my Window but do not cause a WM_KEYDOWN message.

It seems that the created Edit Window does not use my WndProc. How can I change that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `WndProc` don't get `WM_KEYDOWN` messages because, if the user is typing inside the edit control, it means that it has the focus (not your window), so they are sent to the *edit control* window proc, not yours. However, the edit control window proc will send notifications to your `WndProc` (his *parent window* proc).

So, if you only want to react to the user *changing* the content of your child edit control, you don't need another window procedure. Your current `WndProc` will receive `EN_CHANGE` notification code through a `WM_COMMAND` message.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761676(v=vs.85).aspx

---

If you really want to catch `WM_KEYDOWN` messages, you need to subclass the edit control, like this:

```
OldWndProc = (WNDPROC)SetWindowLongPtr (hButton, GWLP_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR)NewWndProc);
```

You also need to define a new windows procedure (the `NewWndProc`), that should handle `WM_KEYDOWN` message (and any other message you want to handle). You also need to call `OldWndProc` as you would call `DefWndProc` in a standard `WndProc`, unless you want to prevent the edit control to do its normal processing.

For details on subclassing, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773183(v=vs.85).aspx

### Edit

Responding to OP comment here.

If your window is a dialog box, you should be notified of enter key, in your `WndProc`:

```
 case WM_COMMAND:

      if(wParam == IDOFDEFBUTTON || wParam == IDOK) ...
```

See https://support2.microsoft.com/Default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;Q102589

To be honest, I never took the time to understand what a dialog box *really* is. But if I recall correctly, you can get your window to get theses special notifications by calling IsDialogMessage in your message pump:

```
if(!IsDialogMessage(hWnd,&msg)) {
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
 }
```

For interesting information about `IsDialogMessage`, see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/04/16/10293933.aspx

If this doesn't give you enough control, you probably have to subclass the edit control.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer. So I see `EN_CHANGE` gets fired when ever something happened in the child control. But is there a way to get WHAT happened with it? For example which key was pressed? Would be very handy if I could handle a key down of the Enter Key. Or will I need to subclass for that?

Answer (score 2):

Your call to CreateWindowsEx creates a new window with "EDIT" wnd class having its own Window procedure. You need a new WndProc and set it to the newly created window (whose handle is returned by CreateWindowEx) via SetClassLong function